# Reset button in child1 to reset input/state of child2

Tags: reactjs

How do I make it so when reset button on Right is clicked - every input field in Left resets to an empty string ("") Thanks!

Parent comp:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Left from "./Left";
import Right from "./Right";
import "./App.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [billAmount, setBillAmount] = useState(0);
  const [personAmount, setPersonAmount] = useState(0);
  const [selectedTip, setSelectedTip] = useState(0);
  const [perCost, setPerCost] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div id="content" className="main__cont">
      <Left
        billAmount={billAmount}
        setBillAmount={setBillAmount}
        personAmount={personAmount}
        setPersonAmount={setPersonAmount}
        selectedTip={selectedTip}        
        setSelectedTip={setSelectedTip}
        perCost={perCost}
        setPerCost={setPerCost}
      />

      <Right
        billAmount={billAmount}
        setBillAmount={setBillAmount}
        personAmount={personAmount}
        setPersonAmount={setPersonAmount}
        selectedTip={selectedTip}
        setSelectedTip={setSelectedTip}
        perCost={perCost}
        setPerCost={setPerCost}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Left child1:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { NumericFormat } from "react-number-format";
import "./left.scss";

Left.propTypes = {
  billAmount: PropTypes.number,
  setBillAmount: PropTypes.func,
  perCost: PropTypes.number,
  setPerCost: PropTypes.func,
  personAmount: PropTypes.number,
  setPersonAmount: PropTypes.func,
  selectedTip: PropTypes.number,
  setSelectedTip: PropTypes.func,

};

const tips = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50];

const TipsInput = ({ label, id, handleChange, name, placeholder }) => {

  const handleInputChange = (values) => {
    const { value } = values;
    const numericValue = parseFloat(
      value.replace(label === "Bill" ? "$" : "", "")
    );
    handleChange(numericValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <NumericFormat
        className="left__input"
        type="text"
        id={id}
        name={name || id}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        allowLeadingZeros={false}
        thousandSeparator=","
        prefix={label === "Bill" ? "$" : ""}
        onValueChange={handleInputChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

TipsInput.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
};

export default function Left({
  billAmount,
  setBillAmount,
  perCost,
  setPerCost,
  personAmount,
  setPersonAmount,
  selectedTip,
  setSelectedTip,
}) {

  const isBillEmpty = billAmount === "";

  const handleTipClick = (percentage) => {
    setSelectedTip(percentage / 100);
    console.log(percentage / 100);
  };

  const calculatePerPeronAmount = (tip) => {
    if (personAmount > 0 && billAmount !== "") {
      setPerCost(
        ((1 + 0.01 * tip) * parseFloat(billAmount)) / parseFloat(personAmount)
      );
    } else {
      setPerCost(0);
    }
    console.log(typeof billAmount, typeof personAmount);

  };
  console.log("billAmount:", billAmount);
  console.log("personAmount:", personAmount);
  console.log("perCost:", perCost);

  return (
    <div className="left">
      <div className="left__group">

        <TipsInput handleChange={setBillAmount} label="Bill" placeholder="$" />
      </div>
      <div className="left__group">
        <label htmlFor="left__text">Select Tip %</label>
        <div className="tip">
          {tips.map((tip) => {
            return (
              <button
                className={`tip__btn ${isBillEmpty ? "disabled" : ""}`}
                disabled={isBillEmpty}
                onClick={() => {                 calculatePerPeronAmount(tip);                  handleTipClick(selectedTip);
                }}
                key={tip}>
                {tip}%
              </button>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="left__group">
        <TipsInput
          handleChange={setPersonAmount}
          label="Number of People"
          placeholder="People"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Right child2:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./right.scss";
Right.propTypes = {
  billAmount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  setBillAmount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  perCost: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  setPerCost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  personAmount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  setPersonAmount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  selectedTip: PropTypes.number.isRequired,  
  setSelectedTip: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default function Right(props) {
  const isResetDisabled = props.billAmount === 0 || props.personAmount === 0;

  let tipAmount = props.perCost - props.billAmount / props.personAmount;

  tipAmount =
    isNaN(tipAmount) || !isFinite(tipAmount) || tipAmount < "" ? 0 : tipAmount;


  let perTotal = props.billAmount / props.personAmount + tipAmount;

  perTotal =
    isNaN(perTotal) || !isFinite(perTotal) || perTotal < "" ? 0 : perTotal;

  return (
    <div className="right">
      <div className="right__group">
        <div className="leftmain__cont">
          <div className="right__text">
            <p className="right__label">Tip Amount</p>
            <p className="right__textsmall">/ person</p>
          </div>
          <h3 className="right__inbtn">${tipAmount.toFixed(2)}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="rightmain__cont">
          <div className="right__text">
            <p className="right__label">Total</p>
            <p className="right__textsmall">/ person</p>
          </div>
          <h3 className="right__inbtn">${perTotal.toFixed(2)}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button className="right__btn" disabled={isResetDisabled}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Common parent: Tried lifting up state from left to parents, and then creating the resetvalue in parents and bringing it into child2 as props but clicking the reset button only resets the value in child2 component.

Answer (score 0):

If all the state's are saved in `<App />`, you can define a `reset` function:

```
const resetAllValues = () => {
    setBillAmount('');
    setPersonAmount('');
    setSelectedTip('');
    setPerCost('');
}
```

Then pass that to `<Right />`:

```
<Right
    resetAllValues={resetAllValues}
    ...
```

And call it `onClick` of the reset button in `<Right />`:

```
<button onClick={resetAllValues} className="right__btn" disabled={isResetDisabled}>
    Reset
</button>
```